# How to solve this issue "java.lang.IllegalStateException: 2 built-in Robo scripts are applicable."

Tags: android, exception

Recently i got this crash in pre-launch report from google. I have searched but found nothing about this. i'm adding below details which i got from googleplay console.

> Issue: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 2 built-in Robo scripts are applicable.
>
> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1077
>
> Process: androidx.test.tools.crawler:robov2crawldriver, PID: 21158

```
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.obfuscated.z.q.b(PatternCompiler.java:43)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.intelligence.BuiltInRoboScriptsActionController.getBuiltinRoboscriptFromCandidates(BuiltInRoboScriptsActionController.java:92)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.intelligence.BuiltInRoboScriptsActionController.getNextAction(BuiltInRoboScriptsActionController.java:33)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.intelligence.DelegatingActionController.getNextAction(DelegatingActionController.java:5)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.CoreController.performActions(CoreController.java:129)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.CoreController.crawl(CoreController.java:105)
at androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.CoreController.run(CoreController.java:34)
```

Comment: Just got the same thing. My guess is that there's something wrong with the robot they use to test the apps with. Did you get any similar reports from users or just the pre-launch tests?

Comment: Only pre-launch tests.

Comment: Are you using MS AppCenter (or HockeyApp)?

Comment: @Barryrowe.. No.i have uploaded to playstore and get this crash from them.

Comment: @HussnainHashmi I have seen the same error in the Play Console when using the AppCenter SDK with Distribute enabled. Does your app jump over to a browser for authentication or anything upon opening that could stop the crawler from being able to detect your app as active?